# Why LLMs tend to use Greek mythology when asking them to write stories about deities?

Tags: llm

Try using "Write a story about sea gods", "Write a story about underworld gods", or other phrases referencing gods as a prompt. They tend to use Greek mythology gods when a specific mythology is not mentioned. Why?

I have used GPT-3.5, GPT-4 and LLaMA V2. Not sure about the behavior in other LLMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a large portion of the data relating to polytheism in their dataset is from Greek mythology... obviously. Think about how much the Greeks wrote on the subject compared to other cultures. What you put in is what you get out with these models. There's nothing surprising here. Try using negative prompts for "Greek" and related words if you prefer something else.

---

**Edit:** to take it further and address holydragon's comment, we can:

1. Ask: [How much writing from ancient Greece is actually preserved?](https://www.quora.com/How-much-writing-from-ancient-Greece-is-preserved-Is-it-a-finite-amount-that-someone-could-potentially-read)
2. Ask: [How many Classical Chinese Texts/Manuscripts survive to this day?](https://www.reddit.com/r/classicalchinese/comments/17s36qo/how_many_classical_chinese_textsmanuscripts/)
3. Keep asking similar questions for classical literature originating in polytheistic cultures...
4. Attempt to get statistics for how much of all that has been translated into English.
5. Ask the people who trained the model how much classical Greek literature was fed into the model versus classical literature from other societies. This might require some data science magic to measure according to that specific criteria. Still, in the end it all comes down to: **what was in the training data?** ;-)

Comment: Your answer could be better by citing some sources of the claim.